# MUDTAB - How to capture and manage the error in the blazor component

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

```
@page "/mf"

<h3>MudtabIndexForm</h3>


<MudTabs  Elevation="0" Outlined="true" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item One" ID='"pn_one"' >
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>MoveIndex(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Two" ID='"pn_two"' >
           <MudButton OnClick="()=>MoveIndex(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Three"   ID='"pn_three"'>
           <MudButton OnClick="()=>MoveIndex(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Four" ID='"pn_four"'>
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>MoveIndex(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item five" ID='"pn_five"' >
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>MoveIndex(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>


<br />
<br />

<input type="text" @bind="@activeIndex" />

  
@code
{
    int activeIndex = 0;

    private  async void MoveIndex(int _index)
    {
        
            activeIndex = activeIndex + 1;
        
    }
}
```

This is a simple code, all it does is pressing next button takes you to the next tab. The problem is when its in last tab, when i press the next button it gives me an error. I understand I can remove the next button in the last tab but is there a way to capture the error and reset the tab. Coz the tabs are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal because you don't use the _index in your "Moveindex" function.
Try this better method :

```cs
<h3>MudtabIndexForm</h3>


<MudTabs  Elevation="0" Outlined="true" @ref="tabs" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item One" ID='"pn_one"' >
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>Activate(1)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Two" ID='"pn_two"' >
           <MudButton OnClick="()=>Activate(2)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Three" ID='"pn_three"'>
           <MudButton OnClick="()=>Activate(3)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item Four" ID='"pn_four"'>
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>Activate(4)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Item five" ID='"pn_five"' >
          <MudButton OnClick="()=>Activate(0)">next</MudButton>
    </MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>


<br />
<br />

<input type="text" @bind="@activeIndex" />

  
@code {
    int activeIndex = 0;
    MudTabs tabs;
    void Activate(int index)
    {
        tabs.ActivatePanel(index);
    }
}
```

the most effective way is to use a foreach loop and a condition in your function.